# After doing an fsck of a partition, the partition is now empty

Tags: fsck

I'm sorry if the title is misleading however I did not know how to ask the question in a better way.

At work I had to install windows on a machine that had debian. I has three partitions one for root, one for home and one for swap. In order to make space for windows I wanted to reduce the size of the partition for home (from 950 Gb to about 650 Gb where only 150 Gb were occupied). I had done this a bunch of times before and did not have any problems (was using a GParted Live CD). However the resizing got stuck and after an hour (it had never taken more than maybe 15 minutes in any other machines with the same sizes) I stopped the process.

Needless to say Debian booted and could not mount the home (which is understandable). I ran the command fsck -y /dev/sda6 (as asked by the OS) and it stayed for good long while saying that there were multiple references to inodes and wheather I wanted to clone them (the -y option was to say yes to all). Each of these question was for a specific file (I could see the indivual names for pdfs, codes and such) in the machine. After it was done, I rebooted the system, Debian started perfectly, however there was no data in the home. I thought that It was attempting to recover the data. I was clearly wrong.

Can any one tell me what happened? Are all the files lost? If so, what where all those question about cloning the data??

Comment: Is there anything in `/home/lost+found`?

Comment: Yes!! It was full of folders and files with name format #HUGE_NUMBER which I suspect was the INODE number. There might still yet be something salvagable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in aborting a file system shrinking half-way through you have probably unrecoverably roached the file system; that is, you won't get it back as it was.

Secondly, the `fsck` seems to have reconnected a bunch of valid-but-disconnected inodes under `/home/lost+found`, and you're going to go through this directory hoping to find important files.

The lessons to learn from this are firstly, to `fsck` a file system before resizing it, especially if shrinking it.  Secondly, not to interrupt a FS resize.  And thirdly, your backup strategy is unfit-for-purpose, and needs a major overhaul.

Comment: The reason I stopped the resizing was becacuase the processed had hang. No cpu nor HDD usage. I've never talked a backup strategy because there was none. Otherwise I would not have bothered to ask the question. Thank you anyways.